# Why and how does the inclusion of random effects in mixed models influence the fixed-effect intercept term?

Tags: mixed-model, intercept

The question is best illustrated by this example which uses a dataset (in library `faraway`) and `lme4` library (both in R).  This intercept-only model is only for illustrative purposes.

```r
    library(lme4)
    library(faraway)
    data(epilepsy)
    log(mean(epilepsy$seizures))
          #expected intercept in intercept only model = 2.5544
    (Ep1a=glm(seizures~1, family=poisson, data=epilepsy))
          #intercept term =2.554 as expected.
    (Ep1b=glmer(seizures ~ 1 + (1|id), family=poisson, 
           data=epilepsy))#intercept term =2.214.
```

```
-------results----
1. simple glm
```

```r
    Call:  glm(formula = seizures ~ 1, family = poisson, 
             data = epilepsy)
    Coefficients:(Intercept)  2.554  
    
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  
     ['glmerMod']
    Family: poisson ( log )
    Formula: seizures ~ 1 + (1 | id) 
    Random effects:
     Groups Name        Std.Dev.
     id     (Intercept) 0.7795  
    Number of obs: 295, groups: id, 59
    Fixed Effects:
    (Intercept)  
          2.214
```

My understanding is that the inclusion of the random term (id) tells the model that there is a repeated measures across subject (in this case).  I can understand that this allows for the non-independence of the data: there are fewer than n=295 independent data points. But why does the fixed-effect intercept value decrease? Are there circumstances where it would increase?

I note from the following website:
http://www.danielezrajohnson.com/glasgow_workshop.R
the following in relation to a model unrelated to the one i've specified above (suggest you search for "average speaker"):

> "...this model has random effects for speaker and word.
> The fixed effects reported are for a sort of average speaker and word. However,
> word, especially, tends to be a very skewed variable. There will always be a few
> very common words, that may favor or disfavor the response. The mixed model
> largely counteracts this weighting."

In my real example, all the coefficients (from a two categorical factor, crossed design with random-intercept-and-slope random effect - such that there are DistClaz dependencies within ID but Treat is independent) are considerably less than the corresponding mean values for those factor combinations as apparent in the raw data.

```
Results-----------------------------------
```

```r
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood 
     ['glmerMod']
    Family: poisson ( log )
    Formula: RCP ~ Treated * DistClaz + (1 + DistClaz | ID) 
          AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance 
     69246.20  69307.43 -34611.10  69222.20 
    Random effects:
     Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr       
     ID        (Intercept) 12.945   3.598               
               DistClazAZE 11.418   3.379    -0.63      
               DistClazRef  8.769   2.961    -0.80  0.71
    Number of obs: 1215, groups: ID, 344
    Fixed effects:
                               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept)                  2.2528     0.4240   5.313 1.08e-07 ***
    TreatedTreated              -2.1244     0.4916  -4.321 1.55e-05 ***
    DistClazAZE                  1.5925     0.5506   2.892  0.00382 ** 
    DistClazRef                  2.6302     0.3614   7.277 3.41e-13 ***
    TreatedTreated:DistClazAZE   0.3613     0.6110   0.591  0.55428    
    TreatedTreated:DistClazRef   0.7068     0.4201   1.682  0.09248 .  
    ---
    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                (Intr) TrtdTr DsCAZE DstClR TT:DCA
    TreatedTrtd -0.862                            
    DistClazAZE -0.500  0.431                     
    DistClazRef -0.828  0.714  0.556              
    TrtdT:DCAZE  0.450 -0.525 -0.901 -0.501       
    TrtdTrt:DCR  0.712 -0.830 -0.478 -0.860  0.583
    ------------------------------------------END

These are the log(means) for the combinations:

    Results-------------------------------------
                 CE      AZE      Ref
    No EMB  5.454940 5.808012 6.273650
    Treated 3.626005 4.387088 5.253717
    -------------------------------------------END
```

The fixed-effect intercept value (2.2528) relates to No EMB:CE (mean =5.4549)- but is this in relation to a 'sort-of-average' ID?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider that you are not predicting a single intercept, but a distribution (random intercepts) across a nonlinear link function. Remember http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality , which basically tells you that in general f(mean(x) !=  mean(f(x))

If I look at the values in your example and roughly estimate that we have an intercept of 2, random effect variance of 3, and a log link, I expect a log mean on the response of

```r
    log(mean(exp(rnorm(100, 2, 3))))
```

which gives 5.036582, roughly fitting to your raw values.

So, to answer your general question: if you have a nonlinear link, a random effect can change the intercept because the random term is applied on a nonlinear link function.

Model misspecification could be another reason for changes in the intercept (e.g. that the random effects are not normal), but I suspect the former reason explains most of your puzzle.